# Excel vba import multiple xml

Tags: excel, xml, vba

My first post so be kind! I'm trying to import multiple xml files using a schema but using a cell reference as part of the file name. The cell reference is a staff number so this is only to import xml files with that user's ID in the filename.

However, its only importing one file into my schema table instead multiples.

```
Sub ImportMyFiles()

Dim strFile As String, strPath As String, Num As Long, LR As Integer, UsrID As String

UsrID = Sheets("All_Fields").Range("A2")
strPath = "C:\QuAD_Output\"
strFile = Dir(strPath & UsrID & "*.xml")
Num = 0

While strFile <> ""

    ActiveWorkbook.XmlMaps("QuAD_Schema_Map1").Import URL:= _
    (strPath & strFile)

    strFile = Dir

    Num = Num + 1

    LR = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    LR = LR + 1
    Cells(LR, "A") = strFile
Wend
MsgBox "This code ran successfully for " & Num & " XML file(s)", vbInformation
End Sub`
```

Comment: Ignore the above, have solved the issue. I needed to amend the xml properties to 'Append new data to existing tables'

Comment: You can delete your question ...

Comment: You are welcome to [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), especially if you think the answer will help future visitors to the question. Or you can delete the question.

Answer (score 0):

See above, managed to resolve the issues with the table properties. Hope this helps someone else

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).